# Pulling User Account info in asp.net/c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I'm relatively new to asp.net and c#, but have learned a ton in the past few months.  My question probably has a relatively simple solution, but it's escaping me.

I currently have a site setup with user registration and authentication through the standard asp.net membership tables.  I'm trying to create a "My Account" page that users can go to when logged in that will display information about their accounts pulled from other tables.

How do I indicate the logged in "UserName" value as the input parameter for the account information tables that I need to query?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you're using .NET Membership Provider, you can get info about currently logged in user by doing the following:

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
Guid userID = (Guid)user.ProviderUserKey;
string username = user.UserName;
```

**EDIT**: I guess it is overkill to use Membership.GetUser() if only thing you need is UserName.
Use **HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name** as others suggests if UserName is the only thing you need.

Answer (score 1):

try User.identity.name

```
httpcontext.current.user.identity.name
```

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx. The Name property is the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name